# How to split a string with space delimiter in google apps script

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

I want to get the first space delimited string out of a longer string with multiple words in it.  Lots of examples, all of which do something like .split(" ").  Google Apps script tells me that split can't take null as a parameter.  I tried setting a variable to " ", even tried String.fromCharCode(32), but GAS tells me that's null.

Search, indexOf have the same issue -- GAS tells me it can't do those with a null argument.  How do I tell GAS that a single space is not a null?

Comment: Strange. What if you use a regex like `split(/\s/)`? Or `split(/\x20/)`?

Comment: This works for me. `var testString = "This is my string."; var splitString = testString.split(" ");`  When I run this in the debugger, I end up with splitString being `["This", "is", "my", "string."]`   Maybe your syntax is off someplace?  Can you edit your post to include a sample and also make sure there is a value to what you are splitting?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's your "string" variable that's `null`.

Comment: Yes, the string variable was null.  the method file.description was returning a null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this was a case of the string being null in some cases.  I was using the file method getDescription.  After using Logger a bunch, I found the problem and I solved those some cases by this check.

```
  var desctext = file.getDescription();

  if ( desctext == null) { desctext = " ; ; ; "};
```

It's been many years since I've done anything with REGEX, and is was confusing then.  Any suggestions on a good site for learning it?

I also changed my delimiter to a semicolon, even though it makes the user input more tedious.

The background is that I'm writing a script to work with a photo inventory where I want to keep the important information in the photo's EXIF.  Not sure if Google is actually storing it there, but in any case the only fields available aside from the date and filename is the description.  So I'm having the users type in coded filenames and descriptions with semicolon delimiters to indicate things like category, item name, status and value.